# Insert function not working in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am trying to insert bulk data in a model using Eloquent ORM. I have created an array of arrays like following:

```
$data array(
    array('email' => 'taylor@example.com', 'votes' => 0),
    array('email' => 'dayle@example.com', 'votes' => 0),
    //...

)
```

I have a model say `ModelA` and I am trying to insert data in the model as follows:

```
ModelA::insert($data);
```

No syntax errors are showing up and no data is being inserted in the table. Could you please help with what could be the reason?

Also if I use this:

```
DB::table('tableX')->insert($data)
```

And there is no table named `tableX` or there is a typo in the table name still I don't get any errors. Is this normal. I am using Laravel 4.2.

Surprisingly this code works on my friend's system. I am not able to figure out the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Have you created your migrations?

Comment: yes..Migrations are created and I have also made sure that the data to be inserted in correct and matches with the table schema.